# How to multiply with vim

Tags: vim

I have a CSS file where everything is slightly too large, so I want to replace every occurrence of `$size px` by `$size*0.75 px` (for example `100px` to `75px` and so on).

How do I do that with vim? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This command may give you a hand:

```
%s/\d\+\ze\s*px/\=float2nr(submatch(0)*0.75)/g
```

This will change:

```
200 px
100px
777px
```

into:

```
150 px
75px
582px
```

### add explanation

This is a `:s` command, we first find the numbers before the `px`, in replacement part, I used replacement expression, which does the calculation. The `submatch(0)` will reference the numbers we just found. `float2nr()` function is just for getting integer result.

In vim :h :s :h \ze and :h sub-replace-expression there are very detailed explanations

Comment: @iblue in vim `:h :s` `:h \ze` and `:h sub-replace-expression` there are very detailed explanations

Comment: @iblue added some brief explanation.

Comment: for `float` numbers use `str2float`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget about the expression register where you can do simple arithmetic: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/simple-calculations-with-vims-expression-register/

[image: Vim commands and effects]